# Why default value of attached property is not shown?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want a TextBlock to show the default value of an attached property, but it doesn't work.

XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MyData}" />
```

Attached Property

```
public class MyDependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyData", typeof(string), typeof(TextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("MyDependencyObject"));


    public static string GetMyData(DependencyObject dpo)
    {
        return (string)dpo.GetValue(MyDataProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyData(DependencyObject dpo, string value)
    {
        dpo.SetValue(MyDataProperty, value);
    }
}
```

When I set MyData's value, it works well.

```
<TextBlock local:MyDependencyObject.MyData="Test"
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MyData}" />
```

Comment: So you want to automatically atrtach MyDependencyObject to *all* TextBlocks in your whole application? This is not how it works.

Comment: Really? Account Number 3 with the same question? Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data binding to an attached property requires a `Path` in parentheses, see [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#propertypath-for-objects-in-data-binding):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                          Path=(local:MyDependencyObject.MyData)}"/>
```

The attached property declaration must use the declaring class as `ownerType` argument to [RegisterAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?view=netframework-4.8#system-windows-dependencyproperty-registerattached(system-string-system-type-system-type-system-windows-propertymetadata))

```
public class MyDependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MyData",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyDependencyObject), // here
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("MyDependencyObject"));

    public static string GetMyData(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(MyDataProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMyData(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(MyDataProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Although the attached property was never explicitly set on the TextBlock, it will show the "MyDependencyObject" default value.